# Mozilla plugin get the previous tab url of the most recent tab

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have a question about how to get the previous tab url in Mozilla plugin after adding a new tab.

The flow is having Tab_A focused, when user click a button, a new tab Tab_B will be added and focused. Tab_B will need the url of Tab_A for processing.

My current solution is, before the new tab Tab_B is loaded (by using listener), i save the url of Tab_A into my extension nsIPrefBranch, so i can read this url when Tab_B (window) is loaded.

I am just wondering if there is a better way of retrieving Tab_A's url in this case, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know getting the previously closed is not defined in docs but doing that isn't difficult as well. You can create a global variable on the overlay.js and store the previously closed tab. I think you don't even need to store it in the preferences incase you want to continue from previously Firefox closed session.

Answer (score 0):

When tab B's document loads, its referrer should be tab A's URL, and its opener will be tab A's contentWindow (assuming it was opened by script in tab A).